# Spring Rest controller return only status (restrict returning response value)

Tags: java, spring-boot, coding-style, response, spring-restcontroller

Usually in spring boot we are using ResponseEntity return type for rest controllers which can contain **or** HttpStatus **or** {HttpEntity, HttpStatus} pair.

For example:

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "api/greetings/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Greeting> deleteGreeting(@PathVariable("id") BigInteger id) {
    boolean deleted = delete(id);
    if (!deleted) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

As you can see here I am returning **only** HttpStatus.

**So the questions are:**
1. What should be correct return type in this kind of situations?:
 How to tell(in programming language :) ) that method will return **only** HttpStatus, and somehow prevent possability of returning something else(HttpEntity)?
By saying "prevent" I mean that you will get **compilation error** if you will send **both** status and body.
2. What should be MediaType assigned to "produces" attribute of "DeleteMapping" annotation?:
 How to tell that it should not produce anything?

P.S. Possibly this is a beginner question, but I haven't found any sources explaining techniques used in this kind of situations.

**Possible solutions: creating restrictions is not solved**
Here is possible solution, but I think that there should be better way:

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "api/greetings/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteGreeting(@PathVariable("id") BigInteger id) {
    boolean deleted = delete(id);
    if (!deleted) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was distracted. What you have now is fine. Alternatively, you could change your return type to `HttpStatus` and write a `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` that will handle it appropriately by just setting the status code and marking the request as handled.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I have tried with returning HttpStatus, but I was getting it as a plain string (not as a status of request). I will check HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler. Meanwhile I will put in the description, possible solution (not full), so that people can try to suggest better variants. thanks again!

Comment: There is a good rule in stackoverflow: If you down-vote, then consider writing a comment, to help the person who have wrote the question

Comment: It depends on what you want. I mean if you want to send back the not-deleted greeting object, then the proper way is what you mentioned:

method return type: ResponseEntity<?> , with greeting object: return new ResponseEntity<Greeting>(HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED);, and with only status: return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);

if you do not want to return the object, then simply use return new ResponseEntity<> or String as a return type

Comment: As you can see I have added that kind of solution to the description. The problem with this solution is that it doesn't add restrictions, it is still not restricted to create response with an Object. The restriction should be done with method declaration part